# Particle же vs Particle -то

Tags: выбор-слова, словоупотребление

What is the difference in the meaning between the particles "же" and "-то"?

For example,

Он же не пришёл.
Vs.
Он-то не пришёл.

Comment: Barbara, there's an excellent book called Particles in Colloquial Russian by A. N. Vasilyeva, which explains all the particles, gives examples and has exercises: http://www.amazon.com/Particles-Colloquial-Russian-A-Vasilyeva/dp/1410203336/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1407292450&sr=8-1&keywords=particles+in+colloquial+russian

Answer (score 8):

Thaaaaats a million-dollar question. :)

Particles have some specific uses. Learn them. As to the general outline:

- in a converstation there is information you know and someting new. A message. There is also some background knowledge (lots of stuff) and some information *currently activated* in you mind
- **же** in such context points to the information you think a listener should know about your object but seems to have activated the opposite. For example, "Он же не пришёл" implies that the listener *knows* that a person did not come but fails to use that in current situation (i.e. acts as though the person came). Usually when "же" is used, the information that *should* be known and the information that the listener seems to use are mutually exclusive.

  - note that "же" is also used in "тогда же" (at the same time as), "те же" (the same people/objects), "там же" (right there, at the place already mentioned) and so on. "Он же" can sometimes be a member of that group, though, that requires some context and syntax.
- **то** is a contrasting particle used when you discuss diferent statements that suit different "objects". The information *"A-то has property B"* is (you think) known to the listener but not activated, so you draw attention to it. That does not mean that the listener thinks elsewise! Here you have "не пришёл" as a characteristic. Using "-то" you can make an object to stand out as the one possessing that property or ask a question about that:

  - *Он-то не пришёл* = "Well, he, of all people, has not come".
  - *А он-то пришел?* = "And as for him, did he come?"

Difficult, I know. But it is hard to give a more detailed explanation when the question is THAT generic.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can boil it down to how focused the emphasis is. With *-то* it's narrowed down to a single word, while *же* acts more on the whole message. To me the both particles have contrasting feel to them, just the more focus, the more contrast.

Some examples (bracketed is even more contrast):

```
- За работу!
- Он не пришёл.
```

He was supposed to come but never did, and apparently this makes the work impossible.

```
- За работу!
- [Но] он же не пришёл!
```

Why would you ask to start working when the guy is not here? (I guess this "assumed" sentence is what Shady_arc meant by saying "listener should know about your object but seems to have activated the opposite")

```
- За работу!
- [Но] он же не пришёл!
- [Это] он-то не пришёл?!
```

He in fact did come. It's totally improbable a person like him wouldn't.

The context is important but simply put *он же не пришёл* = [the reason is the fact] he didn't come, *он-то не пришел* = [everybody came but] he didn't come.

Answer (score 0):

же - yet, after all, at last
*то* - that, this, the
Он *же* не пришёл. - *же* puts accent at "came" (he didn't came after all)
Он-*то* не пришёл. - whereas *то* is rather a pronoun than a pointing particle, a version of the word "that". and is directing thus at exactly at who we talking about. if you wish may think of it as of english particle 'the' in a way. then one of possible translations would be as follows - that he then didn't came

Comment: I agree that "-то" makes accent on "He", but I'm not so sure that "же" makes accent on coming. I would rather say that it only indicates that the event didn't happen.

Comment: I don't think that explanation for "-то" makes sense in any language. You sure its derivation from "that" provides some understanding the way you describe it?

Comment: https://translate.google.ru/?hl=ru&tab=wT#auto/en/%D0%B6%D0%B5